# Poor performance using .loc in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine certain columns by index of this dataframe, which I achived using a simple pd.cov() function, to calculate the variances and covariances of u_centro, v_centro and w_centro.

[image]

However, when I try to slice some of theses values using .loc, the performance is very slow (much slow!).
For example:

```
df_uu = df.loc[(iz_centro,'u_centro'),'u_centro']
```

where I want all the combinations of u_centro by u_centro. The result is exactly what I wanted, but the time spend to complete this is abusurd, more than 10 minutes.

[image]

the whole data:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlessandroMDO/LargeEddySimulation/master/sd.csv

Comment: is your index unique?

Comment: try: `df.xs('u_centro', level=1, axis='index', drop_level=False)`

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. But there's a reason to .loc fail in this case?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing all of your code. It appears like you're looping through values of `iz_centro` and appending to an output dataframe. Appending will be slow. But again, that's just conjecture.

Comment: I just applied an df.groupby('iz_centro').cov() to this csv: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XzpNoyVLrhV7whdngf8A5IiqTujBmx3Q/view, resulting in that dataframe that I have posted. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to do this, but the best performance is using vectorization functions like `xs` (thanks @Paul H) or boolean masks for example:

```
 startime = datetime.now()

 mask = df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'u_centro'
 df.loc[mask]

 print(datetime.now() - startime) # 0:00:00.001417
```

I don't know if `1417 µs` are a big deal in this case.